# I cant access a JWT token from a get request in express

Tags: javascript, express, get

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp()
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const initizalize = require('./passportConfig');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())


const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(cookieParser());

const db = admin.firestore()


app.get('/checkToken', function(req, res) {
  console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies.token);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});



exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

[Example Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wniZ5.png)

I can see on chrome dev tools that there is a token there but for some reason the token is undefined when the path /checktoken is called.

Comment: How are you sending the request? Are you using `fetch` or some other api/package?

Comment: using fetch on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `credentials` options in `fetch` options. Allowed values are `'same-origin'` for same-origin requests, `'include'` for all requests, `'omit'` to omit the use of cookies. Fetch by default uses `'omit``. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included)

If you are using `credentials: 'include'`, you must set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `*` at the backend. If you are using `cors` module then simply do `app.use(cors())`, or `app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }))`. Both are same.

Comment: How to I prevent a cors error. I keep getting cors errors "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5001/connorspackman-49d00/us-central1/app/checkToken' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'."

Comment: Well you are importing `cors` module but you are not using it. Insert `app.use(cors())` right before you add any router/paths.

Comment: I am using cors "var corsOptions = {
  orgin: "http://localhost:3000",
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));"

Comment: Are you using the protocol as well like `http://localhost:3000` if yes then check for other issues on the server, like some server side error.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qitZoX5 the only errors I get are client side. I have attached a screen shot of the errors to this link

Comment: use `{ origin: '*' }`, for credentials to be `'include'`, you must set the `origin` to be wildcard(*).

Comment: whats the syntax for that. This is what I have: fetch('http://localhost:5001/connorspackman-49d00/us-central1/app/checkToken',{
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:5001/connorspackman-49d00/us-central1/app',
          'origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
        }
      })

Comment: I have updated the answer, seems like you were confused between front-end backend headers.

Comment: And if you are confused what `credentials` value you should use, then check the documentation from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I figured it out.

Comment: apologies for the confusion.